# ElasticSearch Nest Msearch fn does not bring all results

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

My aim is to send 3 separate queries in one ES request using [multiple search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

I am using NEST client to send query to Elastic search using function below

```
IElasticClient _elasticClient.LowLevel.Msearch<string>(query).Body;
```

Passing as a raw query using curl command works absolutely fine, but NEST MSearch only returns "event_results" and "venue_results" but not "location_results"

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_msearch -d '
{"index" : "search_results"}
{ "size": 0, "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "term": { "partnersites": "16" } }, { "match_phrase_prefix": { "name": "manchester" } } ] } }, "aggs": { "event_results": { "terms": { "field": "name.keyword", "size": 1 }, "aggs": { "top_tag_hits": { "top_hits": { "size": 1, "_source": [ "name", "groupedName", "groupedDisplayName", "groupedUrl", "eventCode", "venueName", "venueTown", "venueId", "venueUrl", "media", "categories.name" ] } } } } } }
{"index" : "search_results2"}
{ "size": 0, "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "term": { "partnersites": "16" } }, { "match_phrase_prefix": { "venueName": "Manchester" } } ] } }, "aggs": { "venue_results": { "terms": { "field": "name.keyword", "size": 1 }, "aggs": { "top_tag_hits": { "top_hits": { "size": 1, "_source": [ "name", "groupedName", "groupedDisplayName", "groupedUrl", "eventCode", "venueName", "venueTown", "venueId", "venueUrl", "media", "categories.name" ] } } } } } }
{"index" : "search_results3"}
{ "size": 0, "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "term": { "partnersites": "16" } }, { "match_phrase_prefix": { "venueTown": "manchester" } } ] } }, "aggs": { "location_results": { "terms": { "field": "name.keyword", "size": 1 }, "aggs": { "top_tag_hits": { "top_hits": { "size": 1, "_source": [ "name", "groupedName", "groupedDisplayName", "groupedUrl", "eventCode", "venueName", "venueTown", "venueId", "venueUrl", "media", "categories.name" ] } } } } } }
'
```

Is any of you know where the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue lies on indention. Try this:

```
    public static string qu = @"{""index"" : ""search_results""}
{ ""size"": 0, ""query"": { ""bool"": { ""must"": [ { ""term"": { ""partnersites"": ""16"" } }, { ""match_phrase_prefix"": { ""name"": ""manchester"" } } ] } }, ""aggs"": { ""event_results"": { ""terms"": { ""field"": ""name.keyword"", ""size"": 1 }, ""aggs"": { ""top_tag_hits"": { ""top_hits"": { ""size"": 1, ""_source"": [ ""name"", ""groupedName"", ""groupedDisplayName"", ""groupedUrl"", ""eventCode"", ""venueName"", ""venueTown"", ""venueId"", ""venueUrl"", ""media"", ""categories.name"" ] } } } } } }
{""index"" : ""search_results2""}
{ ""size"": 0, ""query"": { ""bool"": { ""must"": [ { ""term"": { ""partnersites"": ""16"" } }, { ""match_phrase_prefix"": { ""venueName"": ""Manchester"" } } ] } }, ""aggs"": { ""venue_results"": { ""terms"": { ""field"": ""name.keyword"", ""size"": 1 }, ""aggs"": { ""top_tag_hits"": { ""top_hits"": { ""size"": 1, ""_source"": [ ""name"", ""groupedName"", ""groupedDisplayName"", ""groupedUrl"", ""eventCode"", ""venueName"", ""venueTown"", ""venueId"", ""venueUrl"", ""media"", ""categories.name"" ] } } } } } }
{""index"" : ""search_results3""}
{ ""size"": 0, ""query"": { ""bool"": { ""must"": [ { ""term"": { ""partnersites"": ""16"" } }, { ""match_phrase_prefix"": { ""venueTown"": ""manchester"" } } ] } }, ""aggs"": { ""location_results"": { ""terms"": { ""field"": ""name.keyword"", ""size"": 1 }, ""aggs"": { ""top_tag_hits"": { ""top_hits"": { ""size"": 1, ""_source"": [ ""name"", ""groupedName"", ""groupedDisplayName"", ""groupedUrl"", ""eventCode"", ""venueName"", ""venueTown"", ""venueId"", ""venueUrl"", ""media"", ""categories.name"" ] } } } } } }
";

var result = _elasticClient.LowLevel.Msearch<string>(qu).Body; // Query ES for results.
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible, you don't want to use the "LowLevel" stuff.  Instead, use what is available to you on the `IElasticClient`.  Here is an example of how to use `IElasticClient.MultiSearch` to run 3 searches using the fluent syntax (which is the preferred way to do this).

```
var mSearchResponse = ElasticClient.MultiSearch(msearch => msearch
    .Search<RedemptionES>(
        s1 => s1.Query(
            q=>q.Term(
                t=> t.OnField(f=> f.Id).Value("123")
            )
        )
    )
    .Search<RedemptionES>(
        s2 => s2.Query(
            q => q.Term(
                t => t.OnField(f => f.Id).Value("456")
            )
        )
    )
    .Search<RedemptionES>(
        s3 => s3.Query(
            q => q.Term(
                t => t.OnField(f => f.Id).Value("789")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: My query is massive and converting to IELasticSearch syntax takes a lot of time also elasticsearch team tend to change syntax, so it is harder to maintain. Would it be possible to get the same results, but using raw query?